# Do I need a Primary Key If I'm using 1 to Many Relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, primary-key

I have a table called `branch`

It looks something like.

```
+----------------+--------------+
|     branch_id  |  branch_name |
+----------------+--------------+
|         1      |  TestBranch1 |
|         2      |  TestBranch2 |
+----------------+--------------+
```

I've set the `branch_id` as primary key.

Now my question is related to the next table called `item`

It looks like this.

```
+----------------+-----------+---------------------------+
|     branch_id  |  item_id  |         item_name         |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------------+
|         1      |     1     |  Apple                    |
|         1      |     2     |  Ball                     |
|         2      |     1     |  Totally Difference Apple |
|         2      |     2     |  Apple Apple 2            |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------------+
```

I'd like to know if I need to create a primary key for my `item` table?

**UPDATE**
They do not share the same items. Sorry for the confusion.. A branch can create a product that doesn't exist in the other branch. They are like two stores sharing the same database.

**UPDATE**
Sorry for the incomplete information. 
These tables are actually from two local database...
I'm trying to create a database that can exist on its own but would still have no problem when mixed with another. So the system would just append all the item data from another branch without mixing them up.. The branches doesn't take the `item_id` of the other branches in consideration when generating a `unique_id` for their items. All the databases however may share same `branch` table as reference.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: A PRIMARY KEY is a prerequisite of a table in RDBMS. Without a PRIMARY KEY, it's not really a table!

Comment: @Strawberry Well, it's still a table, but it's not a relation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to know if I need to create a primary key for my item table?

You always<sup>1</sup> need a key<sup>2</sup>, whether the table is involved in a relationship<sup>3</sup> or not. The only question is what *kind* of key?

Here are your options in this case:

1. Make `{item_id}` alone a key. This makes the relationship "non-identifying" and `item` a "strong" entity...

   - Which produces a slimmer key (compared to the second option), therefore any child tables that may reference it are slimmer.
   - Any ON UPDATE CASCADE actions are cut-off at the level of the `item` and not propagated to children.
   - May play better with ORMs.
2. Make a composite<sup>4</sup> key on `{branch_id, item_no}`. This makes the relationship "identifying" and `item` a "weak" entity...

   - Which makes `item` itself slimmer (one less index).
   - Which may be very useful for [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index).
   - May help you avoid a JOIN in some cases (if there are child tables, `branch_id` is propagated to them).
   - May be necessary for correctly modelling ["diamond-shaped" dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164242/533120).

So pick your poison ;)

Of course, `branch_id` is a foreign key (but not key) in both cases.

And orthogonal to all that, if `item_name` has to be unique per-branch (as opposed to per whole table), you need a composite key on `{branch_id, item_name}` as well.

---

*<sup>1</sup> From the **logical** perspective, you always need a key, otherwise your table would be a multiset, therefore not a relation (which is a set), therefore your database would no longer be "relational". From the **physical** perspective, there may be some special cases for breaking this rule, but they are rare.*

*<sup>2</sup> Whether its primary or not is [immaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798682/533120) from the logical standpoint, although it may be important if the DBMS ascribes a special meaning to it, such is the case with InnoDB which [uses primary key as clustering key](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/).*

*<sup>3</sup> Please make a distinction between "relation" and "relationship".*

*<sup>4</sup> Aka. "compound".*

Comment: wow. this really make sense. well actually my database set up is quite unique. I'm trying to pull off a database that can serve a single branch but would have no problem merging two branches that existed separately before. So they could have the same item_ids for their items but I could guarantee that they have different branch_ids because these are made unique before installation. with this set up. I could create local servers and consolidate their data on 1 corporate server without the hassle. Just uploading and updating data.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example data you are using *n to m* relations and not *1 to m*. It should be like this

```
item table
----------
item_id  | item_name
    1    | Apple
    2    | Ball


branch_item table
-----------------
item_id  | branch_id
    1    | 1
    1    | 2
    2    | 1
    2    | 2
```

And your `brach_item` table should have a compound unique key containg `branch_id` and `item_id` to make sure no duplicate entries can be added.

Comment: It would be nice if you also explained why and not just present the solution. He makes it then right this time, but not with the next tables where the situation might be the same.

Comment: @juergen d, I had one doubt, if I should be create the table without pk look like as table, http://a4academics.com/interview-questions/53-database-and-sql/397-top-100-database-sql-interview-questions-and-answers-examples-queries

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. The Primary key is what allows the many to one relationship to exist.

This requirement is already catered for by the branch_id column.

The item_id column is not required for the one-to-many relationship in your example.

Comment: As I have already explained in my update. They do not share the same item. So it's not a many to many relationship.. It's just 1 branch to many items. Each branch maintain a separate list of items. No branch shares an item.

Comment: Understood. I have amended my answer. Just so that you know, in your example item_id does not make sense. On the surface it looks like a primary key, except that each item does not have a unique number. If you changed the item_id column from 1,2,1 and 2 to 1,2,3 and 4 then it would make sense.

Comment: The thing is. this data would actually exist in different branches and the consolidated data would look like this.